# How can I make this Google Apps Script loop efficiently?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making an script that increases the value of a cell by 0.01 until it matches the value of another cell (gets the value, pass through a formula than see if the other cell value matches). The problem is that it takes too long to execute. It was very simple to do on excel, but I don't know how to program in G-Apps Script (neither js).

I guess it's taking too long because it runs on the cloud. There is anyway I can solve it?

Here the code so far:

```
function Calculate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var vF = ss.getSheetByName('magic').getRange('C31').getValue();
  ss.getSheetByName('magic').getRange('C32').setValue(0);
  var vE = ss.getSheetByName('magic').getRange('C32').getValue();

  var vP

  for(vE=0;vE != vP;vE+=0.01){
    ss.getSheetByName('magic').getRange('C32').setValue(vE);
    var qParc = vF - vE;
    ss.getSheetByName('magic').getRange('C3').setValue(qParc);
    vP = ss.getSheetByName('magic').getRange('F3').getValue();

  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It could help you https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices.

Comment: Is the formula constant? What if formula is x^2 and other cell value is -1 ?

Comment: It's a very complex formula, not constant. As the entry rises, the other value reduces. The objective is to find the value where both matches or get the most close of.

Comment: Sounds like this is an optimization problem that you've programmed using a "Spreadsheet Language" (cell values & formulas using those cells + numeric constants). You'll get much faster results if you translate that "spreadsheet program" into JavaScript (variables & formulas using those variables + numeric constants). Additionally, consider using an optimization routine such as Newton's method to more appropriately compute the desired parameter value, rather than just incrementing a fixed amount. Use of an optimization routine could mean you do not need to rewrite your logic into Apps Script

Answer (score 2):

More likely it's running "too long" because `vE != vP` is never false, because the kind of floating point used by JavaScript (IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point, used by most programming languages) is inherently imprecise. Famously, `0.1 + 0.2` is not `0.3` (it's `0.30000000000000004`). As a result, it's unreliable to use `==` or `!=` (or `===` or `!==`) with possibly-fractional numbers. (You're okay if they're integers, provided they're not **really** big ones.)

There probably isn't any need for a loop if you want to update a value to make it match another. Just take the difference and add that to the one you're updating.

But if you do need the loop, replace `!=` with `<`.

```
for (vE = 0; vE < vP; vE += 0.01) {
```

You're also repeating a **lot** of operations, perhaps expensive ones, there. Once you have the object for (say) a sheet or cell, remember that object reference and reuse it:

```
function Calculate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var magic = ss.getSheetByName('magic');
  var c32 = magic.getRange('C32');
  var c3 = magic.getRange('C3');
  var f3 = magic.getRange('F3');
  var vF = magic.getRange('C31').getValue();
  var vE, vP, qParc;

  for (vE = 0; vE < vP; vE += 0.01) {
    c32.setValue(vE);
    qParc = vF - vE;
    c3.setValue(qParc);
    vP = f3.getValue();
  }
}
```

(I also removed an unnecessary `var vE = c32.getValue();` from that, since you immediately overwrite `vE` with `0` at the beginning of the loop. I just added the declaration to the `var` declaring `vP` and, now, `qParc`.)

Comment: thank you for pointing this. The problem is that the loop don't even go too far before Google stops it for taking too long. In other words, the loops is too slow that vE only increases until about 9.55.

I don't know how could I make a simple macro to do it without a loop =/

Comment: @oliddan - I've updated the answer. You were repeating a lot of potentially-expensive operations there...

Comment: @t-j-crowder thank you again! So the problem was the unnecessary calls. I tried to run the code in debug mode and for some reason, it stops at this line "c32.setValue(0);"

Comment: @oliddan - I thought I'd removed that line (I have now), but it should be harmless. The first loop iteration sets 0 in that cell. If it's stopping there, there must be some error, which presumably is reported somewhere...

Comment: If you look at the execution transcript in Google App Script, you'll see (probably) that .setValue() and .getValue() are expensive operations.  Is there any reason you need to continuously update the sheet instead of doing this in memory, and updating after loop? Best practice with GAS and sheets is to update the sheet all at once, generally.

Comment: @Paul the problem is that the loop needs to get the updated value after increasing the value of the cell. Is it possible to like, load the spreadsheet, execute the loop, without calling the expensive operations?

Comment: @oliddan Yes, it's possible but it depends on whether or not you want to show the cell's value increasing for whomever is viewing the sheet, or if you just want the final result.  If you want the final result, just keep the pertinent values in memory, update and compare those, and output the results after the loop.